# Java version statistics

Tags: java, statistics

Where can I see statistics about the most used Java versions?

(I want to develop applications that will run on most systems)

Comment: I think that the reason given for closing does not apply here. This question is not asking to recommend a tool. It is asking for statistics about how widely supported a tool is, which has an objective answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [StatOwl](http://www.statowl.com/java.php), Java 6 has reached a 70% adoption rate.

Comment: For server side apps, you should be able to specify a version to use.

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore. Do you know of an alternative source of this data? Surely the percentage is higher than 70% now for 1.6. I'm interested in whether I should target 1.5 for my library or not.

Comment: @DrewNoakes: unfortunately nothing that's automatically gathered, but here is a recent developer survey which indicates that only 5% of developers are on Java 5 or older: https://typesafe.com/company/news/survey-of-more-than-3000-developers-reveals-java-8-adoption-ahead-of-previous-forecasts

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt, thanks that's a useful link. Probably worth popping it into your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.6, update 11 enabled background upgrades so it will always be current. 70% of java installs are version 1.6. Stick with 1.6

http://www.statowl.com/java.php

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a high percentage of system have very old versions of Java or no Java at all.

I suggest you develop for Java 5. Any system which doesn't have this at least probibly should have it installed.

Comment: +1 I agree, if you're going for max compatability, then 1.5 is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Google trends](http://www.google.com/trends), they have a nice graphical view as well.

It wont show you the most used, but it will show you the most popular according to Google searches etc.

Comment: The most popular will be Java 7, becouse of the developers.

Answer (score 0):

Java 5 has been deprecated for a full year now at this point, leaving Servers that still run it at a full year of security issues that are not patched, and never will be. I'd say stick with Java 6. We don't write Software with Windows 95 or OSX 10.3 in mind either, do we? Sometimes it is time to tell the users to update their software.

Answer (score 0):

Java Tools and Technologies Landscape Report 2016 (Zeroturnaround): https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-tools-and-technologies-landscape-2016/#java-versions

Java version and vendor data analyzed 2017 (Plumbr): https://plumbr.io/blog/java/java-version-and-vendor-data-analyzed-2017-edition